# Reshape matrix into a list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list as follows:

```
 id | value
 ----------
  4     600
  4     899
  7      19
 13    4930
 13     300
  :       :
```

There are multiple ID repeats, and each one has a unique value. I want to turn this into something as follows:

```
id |  list
----------
 4    c(600, 899)
 7    c(19)
13    c(4930, 300)
 :    :
```

Is there a vectorized method of accomplishing this?

---

EDIT:  Extending the first question, is there a simple way to do the same thing for a generic MxN matrix? I.e., turning this:

```
 id | value1  value2
 -------------------
  4     600        a
  4     899        b
  7      19        d
 13    4930        e
 13     300        a
  :       :        :
```

into this:

```
id |  list
----------
 4    list(c(600, 899),c('a','b'))
 7    list(c(19),c('b'))
13    list(c(4930, 300),c('e','a'))
 :    :
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use `tapply` if you want to stick with base functions:

```
tapply(dat$value,dat$id,c)
$`4`
[1] 600 899

$`7`
[1] 19

$`13`
[1] 4930  300
```

Edit:

For your edited problem, I would go with `split` and `lapply`:

```
x <- lapply(split(dat[2:3],dat$id),c,use.names=F)

dput(x)
structure(list(`4` = list(c(600, 899), c("a", "b")), `7` = list(
19, "d"), `13` = list(c(4930, 300), c("e", "a"))), .Names = c("4", "7", "13"))
```

Comment: @Andrie - I updated the question to include a more generic question, do you mind taking a second look?

Answer (score 4):

The functions in package `plyr` should be of help here.

In the following example I assume your data is in the form of a `data.frame` - even if it really is a list, as you say, it should be straight-forward to convert to a data.frame:

```
dat <-   data.frame(
    id = c(4, 4, 7, 13, 13),
    value = c(600, 899, 19, 4930, 300)
)

library(plyr)
dlply(dat, .(id), function(x)x$value)
```

The result is a list as you specified:

```
$`4`
[1] 600 899

$`7`
[1] 19

$`13`
[1] 4930  300

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
  id
1  4
2  7
3 13
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The data is in a `data.frame`, I'm still getting used to R terminology. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just `split()` the data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "id  value
  4     600
  4     899
  7      19
 13    4930
 13     300", header=T)

split(d$value, d$id)
$`4`
[1] 600 899

$`7`
[1] 19

$`13`
[1] 4930  300
```

Comment: I updated the question to include a more generic question, do you mind taking a second look?