# Vectorizing list of lists operation in R

Tags: r, vectorization

Similar to my question yesterday on [reshaping matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9195112/168775), I'm now trying to reshape data frames so I can vectorize my function. In the below code, the main function is `scorecard`. It takes in a data frame called `subset.loans` and `subset.collateral`. I'm wondering whether I can reshape the two frames `loans` and `collaterals`, which both look like this:

```
  LOANS              COLLATERAL           
id | value       id | value   type             
----------       -------------------             
 1     200        1     600      a
 2    4390        1     899      b               
 2     860        2     190      d               
 2    9750        3    4930      e               
 3     600        3     300      a               
 :       :        :       :      :
```

Into this:

```
id | loans             collateral
-----------------------------
 1   c(200)            data.frame(a=c(600,899), b=('a','b'))
 2   c(4390,860,9750)  data.frame(a=c(190), b=c('d'))
 3   c(600)            data.frame(a=c(4930,300), b=c('e','a'))
```

My hope is that if I do that, I can then use one of the `*apply` functions - or something from the `plyr` toolbox - to simply apply the `scorecard` function over the whole thing. If there's a better/easier way, please mention it! The code I'm currently using (with a godforsaken `for` loop) follows:

```cpp
# An Nx2 data frame of loans (ID, amount)
loans <- read.table(...)

# An Mx4 data frame of collaterals to loans (ID, type, value, lien)
collateral <- read.table(...)

# One person (ID) can have >1 loan and >1 collateral, so first just
# find all unique IDs
loans.ID.unique = unique(loans$ID)

# Run an analysis on each ID grouping:
for(n in 1:length(loans.ID.unique)) {

  # ...all loans for that ID...
  subset.loans      <- loans$loans[
                         which(
                           loans$scorecard_id == loans.ID.unique[n])]

  # ...all collateral for that ID...
  subset.collateral <- collateral[
                         which(
                           collateral$scorecard_id == loans.ID.unique[n]),
                         c('type','value','lien')]

  # Output scores for each ID
  scores[n,1]   <- loans.ID.unique[n]
  scores[n,c(2,3)] <- scorecard(loans=subset.loans,
                                collateral=subset.collateral,
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should introduce yourself to the `plyr` package.  Step 1: use `merge` to combine your data into a single data.frame. Step 2: use `plyr::ddply` to do your work in one step.

Comment: @andrie - I've downloaded it but not yet used it. (I just started using R about a month ago, so I have a few things to look into.) If this really is as easy as you say, well, that's just awesome.

Comment: When you start learning R you always have a few things to look into and the better I get with R I find the list of things to look into is growing exponentially :)

Answer (score 3):

**1) No data structure**.  It would be unusual to create such a structure in R.  Suggest you just grab what you need on the fly.  Here `Loans` and `Collateral` are your two input data frames and `loans` and `collateral` are the portions for the current `id` being processed.  Replace the double hashed line of the function below with your own code:

```
ids <- union(Loans$id, Collateral$id)
do.call("rbind", lapply(ids, function(id) {
    loans <- Loans[Loans$id == id, "value"]
    collateral <- Collateral[Collateral$id == id, -1]
    c(id = id, score = sum(loans) - sum(collateral$value)) ##
}))
```

ADDED:

**2) Matrix**. On the other hand, if we really do want to create such a structure it could be done like this:

```
ids <- union(Loans$id, Collateral$id) 
m <- cbind(id = ids,
    loans = lapply(ids, function(id)  Loans[Loans$id == id, "value"]),
    collateral = lapply(ids, function(id)  Collateral[Collateral$id == id, -1])
)

do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) with(m[i,],
   c(id = id, score = sum(loans) - sum(collateral$value))
)))
```

**3) Data Frame**. We could alternately represent the structure as a data frame, `d <- as.date.frame(m)` or the following which is nearly the same:

```
d <- data.frame(id = ids,
  loans = I(lapply(ids, function(id)  Loans[Loans$id == id, "value"])),
  collateral = I(lapply(ids, function(id)  Collateral[Collateral$id == id, -1]))
)
do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) with(d, 
   c(id = id[[i]], score = sum(loans[[i]]) - sum(collateral[[i]]$value))
)))
```

EDIT: Simplified the code that builds `m`.

ADDED: Data frame representation.

Comment: Very interesting. I was effectively trying to create a MATLAB `struct` data type, but this looks much cleaner.

Comment: I have added an example showing how to create such a structure to see how it looks just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to transform your data at all. In fact, the transformation you are looking for is impossible because you can't have a `data.frame` inside a `data.frame`. Instead, just try using `lapply` on your scorecard function.

```
# Read in data
loans=data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,2,3),value=c(200,4390,860,9750,600))
col=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),value=c(600,899,190,4930,300),type=c('a','b','d','e','a'))

# Load in scorecard function
 scorecard = function(subset.loans,subset.collateral) {
    # Do something other than this
    list(subset.loans,subset.collateral)
 }   

# Use lapply
lapply(unique(loans$id),
function (x) scorecard( loans[loans$id==x,] , col[col$id==x,c('type','value')])
)
```

If you wanted to transform your data as you mentioned, you could do something like that with this:

```
loans.agg=aggregate(loans$value,by=list(loans$id),c)
names(loans.agg)=c('id','loans')

col.agg.val=aggregate(col$value,by=list(col$id),c)
names(col.agg.val)=c('id','collateral')

col.agg.type=aggregate(col$type,by=list(col$id),c)
names(col.agg.type)=c('id','type')

# What you probably want
merge(merge(loans.agg,col.agg.val),col.agg.type)
```