# Converting a data.frame to a list of lists

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I convert a data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("af1", "af2"), start=c(100, 115), end=c(114,121))
```

To a list of lists

```
LoL <- list(list(id="af1", start=100, end=114), list(id="af2", start=115, end=121))
```

I've tried things like

```
not.LoL <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(df)))
```

and I'm really not sure what I end up with after this, but it isn't quite right. My requirement is that I can access, say, the first `start` by the command

```
> LoL[[1]]$start
[1] 100
```

the `not.LoL` that I currently have gives me the following error:

```
> not.LoL[[1]]$start
Error in not.LoL[[1]]$start : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Explanations and/or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I should have made it clear that "id" here is actually non-unique - there can be multiple elements under a single ID. So I could do with a solution that doesn't depend on unique IDs to `split` on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshape matrix into a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195112/reshape-matrix-into-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @agstudy: not a duplicate: that one is about ragged arrays and `tapply`, while this one here appears to be rectangular and therefore can be solved using `lapply` as [shown below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730102/1468366).

Comment: @MvG No . See the first solution, he proposes 2 solutions, one with `lapply` which is clearly the same solution proposed here. and second answer using dlply like mine here.

Comment: @MvG `lapply` without split? Can you detail this in an answer please.

Comment: @MvG You are correct - I have no requirement that IDs should be unique. perhaps I should not have called that column "id". The solutions supplied work for me now, but I want to avoid the requirement if possible

Comment: @agstudy, it seems I misread [my favorite answer so far](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730102/1468366), missing the fact that it, too, grouped by `id`. I was reading what I had in mind, not what was actually there…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `plyr` , you can do this

```
dlply(df,.(id),c)
```

To avoid grouping by id , if there are multiple ( maybe you need to change column name , id is unique for me)

```
dlply(df,1,c)
```

Comment: Sorry, using `id` for that column is confusing. Thanks for the `plyr` solution!

Comment: @agstudy after using the second solution in a problem when ID's were not unique, I found that the solution will actually group by the first column. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Mattrition yes you're right. `dlply(df,2,c)` (choose the second column). This solution is not working when the column is not unique. You can accept another solution.

Comment: @agstudy The other solutions have their own problems. A simply way around this is to create a column containing the row names, and then split on that column. This is what I am using.

Answer (score 10):

```
LMAo <- lapply(split(df,df$id), function(x) as.list(x)) # is one way

# more succinctly
# LMAo <- lapply(split(df,df$id), as.list)
```

---

An edited solution as per your comment:

```
lapply( split(df,seq_along(df[,1])), as.list)
```

Comment: This is great and works for my purposes at the moment. However, like @MvG said it is grouping by ID, and I actually don't require that IDs are unique. Is there a way around this?

Comment: can the downvote, explain what is wrong with what I have done, and be a bit ore constructive?

Comment: @user1317221_G why donwvoting this solution?? +1!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `apply` to turn your data frame into a list of lists like this:

```
LoL <- apply(df,1,as.list)
```

However, this will change all your data to text, as it passes a single atomic vector to the function.

Comment: not this might be tricky if you have numeric/character/factors in the data.frame and in the words of @Andrie *"Dragons"*

Comment: +1  for the LoL :) ( the list of list of list  variable name)

Comment: It's annoying that apply returns only character data. Otherwise I love the simplicity of this solution!

Comment: I consider this better than the plyr solution, because of dlply's grouping feature.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, it's quite a bit faster to use `mapply` instead of `split` or `lapply` - however, you have to invoke it via `do.call` so that each column is used independently.

```r
df <- sleep

f <- function(df) {
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(row) {
    df[row, , drop = FALSE]
  })
}

f2 <- function(df) {
  do.call("mapply", c(list, df, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES=FALSE))
}

f3 <- function(df) {
  split(df, seq(nrow(df)))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(df), f2(df), f3(df))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>   f(df) 573.799 607.8375 759.1721 626.0095 752.9465  2861.961   100
#>  f2(df) 114.819 123.5190 155.5185 129.9210 141.4340  1375.573   100
#>  f3(df) 598.774 625.6025 813.6837 634.5855 684.3825 11230.678   100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you are mostly looking to create lists of lists to use in `highcharter`, that same package contains the function `list_parse()` (or `list_parse2()` if you want to remove names). Simply use it like so:

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(id=c("af1", "af2"), start=c(100, 115), end=c(114,121))

LoL <- list_parse(df)
```

After which you can do the indexing you wanted:

```
> LoL[[1]]$start
[1] 100
```