# Convert R dataframe into a list-of-lists

Tags: r

I have a dataframe obtained from a SQL query like so:

```
conn <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user=...)
res <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT fname, lname from users")
```

Now I want to convert it into a list-of-lists, as if I had done this:

```
> list(list('fname'='joe', 'lname'='smith'), list('fname'='sally', 'lname'='smith'))
[[1]]
[[1]]$fname
[1] "joe"

[[1]]$lname
[1] "smith"


[[2]]
[[2]]$fname
[1] "sally"

[[2]]$lname
[1] "smith"
```

I have tried a bunch of variants of `apply` and `lapply`, but nothing seems to be quite right. This is the closest, but it's still off:

```
> lapply(split(res, 1:nrow(res)), function(x) list('fname'=x['fname'], 'lname'=x['lname']))
$`1`
$`1`$fname
  fname
1   Joe

$`1`$lname
  lname
1    Smith


$`2`
$`2`$fname
  fname
2      Sally

$`2`$lname
  lname
2    Smith
```

What is the right way to get a list-of-lists from my dataframe?

Edit: I have tried all the solutions in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730001/converting-a-data-frame-to-a-list-of-lists) but none of them produce my desired output. They give results like this:

```
$`1`
$`1`$fname
[1] "Joe"
```

not:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$fname
[1] "joe"
```

Comment: Please see my edit for why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I think you just want to strip out the names in the higher levels of the list. If `names(myList[[1]])` is something like 1 2 3 4, then assign names to NULL. `sapply` and `vapply` have USE.NAMES arguments that you may set to FALSE.