# difference in R between [[1]] vs $`1`

Tags: r

In R, I have a list-of-lists that prints like this:

```
> ll <- list(list('fname'='joe', 'lname'='smith'), list('fname'='sally', 'lname'='smith'))                                         
> ll
[[1]]
[[1]]$fname
[1] "joe"

[[1]]$lname
[1] "smith"


[[2]]
[[2]]$fname
[1] "sally"

[[2]]$lname
[1] "smith"
```

But if I start with a dataframe (from a SQL query) and obtain a list-of-lists from the `apply` family of functions, it looks like this:

```
> ll2 <- apply(df, 1, as.list)
> ll2
$`1`
$`1`$fname
[1] "joe"

$`1`$lname
[1] "smith"


$`2`
$`2`$fname
[1] "sally"

$`2`$lname
[1] "smith"
```

So I would like to understand (1) what does the different notation signify---especially since both `ll` and `ll2` seem to be a list-of-lists? (2) how can I convert `ll2` (or better yet `df`) into something like `ll`?

For instance in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730001/converting-a-data-frame-to-a-list-of-lists) every answer produces something like `ll2` not `ll`. For instance `lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), as.list)` still looks like `ll2`.

The only answer I've found so far is to loop over `df` and add a new item to a list as I go:

```
> ret <- list()
> ret[[1]] <- list('fname'='joe', 'lname'='smith')
> ret[[2]] <- list('fname'='sally', 'lname'='smith')
> ret
[[1]]
[[1]]$fname
[1] "joe"

[[1]]$lname
[1] "smith"


[[2]]
[[2]]$fname
[1] "sally"

[[2]]$lname
[1] "smith"
```

But I can see that [R people frown on building lists in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508519/how-to-add-elements-to-a-list-in-r-loop). So if you don't like that approach, what is a better one?

Comment: `x$name` works with named elements of lists. If your list doesn't have names, you have to use `x[[num]]`

Comment: Please be aware that `apply` is a very dangerous way to do anything with `data.frame`s. You are risking massive unwanted data coercion. A better idiom would be `lapply(split(df,nrow(df)),as.list)`.

Comment: @joran thanks for the warning. I've also tried `lapply` but it still looks like `ll2` not `ll`. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Frank so can you explain why `apply` and `lapply` create lists with "names" like `1` rather than lists without names?

Comment: The only difference is the presence/absence of names. What specific problem are the names creating? If they aren't creating a concrete problem, what does it matter?

Comment: @joran the library I'm using will only accept inputs like `ll` not `ll2`.

Comment: Remove the names with `unname`.

Comment: I agree with joran about just using unname. I am not sure why each fn behaves as it does with respect to naming the output, but it has never posed a problem / mattered for me.

Comment: Additionally, compare `list("2" = "A", "1" = "B")[[1]]` with `list("2" = "A", "1" = "B")$'1'`. For the sake of creating an `ll` from a "data.frame", you could use `.mapply(list, df, NULL)`